# remove pseudo class of first item

Tags: html, css

I have a simple unordered list:

```
  <ul id="sub_menu">
    <li></li> 
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <!-- and some more -->
  </ul>
```

I removed any of the `list-style-type`s and created my own with a `:pseudo` class

```
#sub_menu ul li:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: #FFFFFF; 
}
```

what I know would like to know is, what would be the CSS selector look like, if I would like to remove the pseudo class for the first `li` item of this list.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exclude the first `li`, using the `:not()` selector:

```
#sub_menu ul li:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "• ";
  color: #FFFFFF; 
}
```

If you need IE8 compatibility, you may use a combination of sibling selectors, like:

```
#sub_menu ul li:first-child ~ li:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: #FFFFFF; 
}
```

**EDIT**

Also, just a side-note... According to your html, the selector is wrong. If the `ul` has the id of `#sub_menu`, it should be

```
#sub_menu li
```

instead of

```
#sub_menu ul li
```

Comment: crossbrowser down to IE 8 working?

Comment: @supersize To support older browsers you could use `#sub_menu ul li:first-child ~li:before`

Comment: Or you could do `#sub_menu ul li:first-child:before {content:''; display:none;}` and it's IE8 compatible.

Comment: @supersize - According to MDN, it's IE9+ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: @supersize - For IE8 compatibility, check the updated answer

Answer (score 3):

The following selectors will both work down to IE7:

```
#sub_menu ul li + li::before
#sub_menu ul li ~ li::before
```

They behave the same as:

```
#sub_menu ul li:not(:first-child)::before
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is the

```
#sub_menu ul li:nth-child(n+2):before {
  content: "• ";
  color: #FFFFFF; 
}
```